# Android client connecting to Rest API

Tags: android, asp.net-core, retrofit2

I have an Android Client which connects to Rest API (aspnet core) & Retrofit 2.
As for my testing and In Most cases API returns response in ~200ms.

BUT - sometimes, could be a minute after a successful fetch, it takes more than few seconds to retrieve data ... and i am not sure why... is it the client or API side?

Again, API in postman returns data within ~200ms ALL the time !

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is probably the server side API that is causing the occasional delay, not the client

Comment: any idea why...? what can i improve there ?

Comment: Whether the issue relates the network or not?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that application pool times out. When this happens first API call can take longer because application needs to be loaded again.

Comment: Yes, thought so - but it happens before the pool times out ...